# Error 404 not found while trying to dockerize php web application

Tags: php, docker, apache

I'm trying to dockerize a php web application, but no luck so far.
In the root of my project I have a folder called public, and index.php is inside it.
So far I created two files, docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile, both on the root of my project.
docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./public:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY ./public /var/www/html

RUN sed -i 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/html/p!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install fileinfo

RUN a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

I build the container and get it started, and when I access http://localhost/ I get:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Does anyone know what I've been missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `index.php` is inside the `public` folder, you may need to configure Apache to use this folder as the document root and enable the rewrite module.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
# Copy the entire project (including Dockerfile) to the image
COPY . /var/www/html
RUN a2enmod rewrite
COPY apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql fileinfo
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./public:/var/www/html/public
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Create a new file called `apache-config.conf` in the root of your project:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration sets the `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/html/public` and allows overrides in the directory block. The `.htaccess` file inside your `public` folder should now be considered.

After making these changes, rebuild your Docker container and see if the issue persists. If it still does not work, check the Apache logs for any error messages that might provide more insight into the problem.